# How to remove selected row in datagridview from csv file?

Tags: c#

I have a "datagridview" which is loaded from csv file. i want to remove slected row in "datagridview" from csv file.

thank you

Comment: Can you put a sample of your code? What have you tried?

Comment: This question is far to vague to be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I would use the code below to read the CSV into a DataTable.  You can make the DataTable the source of the datagridview.  It would be easy to remove row from the datatable than from the datagridview.  The index of the datagridview and the datatable is the same so if a user selects a row from the datagridview to delete the same index of the datatable can be deleted.  The datagridview will automatically be updated when the datatable is changed.

```
   public class CSVReader
    {

        public DataSet ReadCSVFile(string fullPath, bool headerRow)
        {

            string path = fullPath.Substring(0, fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            string filename = fullPath.Substring(fullPath.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(fullPath))
                {
                    string ConStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}" + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR={1};FMT=Delimited\\\"", path, headerRow ? "Yes" : "No");
                    string SQL = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", filename);
                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, ConStr);
                    adapter.Fill(ds, "TextFile");
                    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Table1";
                }
                foreach (DataColumn col in ds.Tables["Table1"].Columns)
                {
                    col.ColumnName = col.ColumnName.Replace(" ", "_");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return ds;
        }
    }​
```